# Rails 3.2 weird views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, each

First time I ask a question on this site, hope you can help me for my 'problem'. :-)

Actually, it's not really a problem in development, but in production...

Here's my problem:

I'm working with **Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 2.1.7**. For this, I'm using ***RubyMine***.
Since the beginning, when I push some data in a hash, the record appears also in an user instance of collection.

I searched in my configuration, in my development.rb, initializers,... But I don't know where it comes! :-(

Because I don't have any reputation on this site, I can't show you what it is, so I will explain it in other way.

I add my User 'Test1' to a tournament **via the view** by clicking on 'sign in'.
My view (I'm using Haml):

## app/views/tournaments/show.html.haml

```
%p#notice= notice
 %p
  %b Name:
   = @tournament.name
 %p
  %b Place:
   = @tournament.place
   = @tournament.to_coordinates
 %p
   = image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@tournament.latitude}%2C#{@tournament.longitude}"

 %p
  %b Nb players max:
   = @tournament.nb_players_max
- if can? :update, @tournament
  = link_to 'Add Match', new_match_path(@tournament.id)
  |
  = link_to 'Add Games', show_games_path(@tournament.id)
  |
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_tournament_path(@tournament)
  |
  = link_to 'Back', tournaments_path
- if @tournament.users.include?(@current_user)
 %p
  you\'re already signed in for this tournament
- else
 = form_for @tournament, url: add_player_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.hidden_field 'tournament_id', :value => @tournament.id
  = f.submit 'Sign in'

 = link_to 'Seed players', seed_players_path(@tournament.id), method: :post

- if @tournament.users.any?
 %ul.list-group
  = @tournament.users.each do |player|
   %li.list-group-item
    = player.pseudo
- else
 %p
  No players for this tournament.

- if @tournament.games.any?
 = @tournament.games.each do |game|
  %h2
   = game.title
   = link_to 'Sign in all players'
- else
 %p
  No games for this tournament. A new game will be added rapidly.
```

by clicking on the sign in button, the user is correctly added in @tournament.users. But this appears also **in the view** just below :

```
- if @tournament.users.any?
 %ul.list-group
  = @tournament.users.each do |player|
   %li.list-group-item
    = player.pseudo
- else
 %p
  No players for this tournament.

[#<User id: 29, country: "BE", nb_victory: nil, nb_defeat: nil, total_points: nil, created_at: "2016-02-16 14:20:36", updated_at: "2016-02-18 10:07:49", first_name: "T", last_name: "T", pseudo: "Test1", email: "test1@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$WRHkX0mN0t1GAEYg8CQPJeVHBg0bVzBmDxpHKtU.g23A...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 3, current_sign_in_at: "2016-02-18 10:07:49", last_sign_in_at: "2016-02-17 09:31:06", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: "Q2rJ8aWYPmttd9XRjKgX", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2016-02-16 14:20:36", unconfirmed_email: nil, avatar: "chat.png", provider: nil, uid: nil, role: "player">]
```

In the HTML code, I can see this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
 <li class="list-group-item"> Test1 </li>
 [#<User id: 29, country: "BE", nb_victory: nil, nb_defeat: nil, total_points: nil, created_at: "2016-02-16 14:20:36", updated_at: "2016-02-18 10:07:49", first_name: "T", last_name: "T", pseudo: "Test1", email: "test1@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$WRHkX0mN0t1GAEYg8CQPJeVHBg0bVzBmDxpHKtU.g23A...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 3, current_sign_in_at: "2016-02-18 10:07:49", last_sign_in_at: "2016-02-17 09:31:06", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: "Q2rJ8aWYPmttd9XRjKgX", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2016-02-16 14:20:36", unconfirmed_email: nil, avatar: "chat.png", provider: nil, uid: nil, role: "player">]
</ul>
```

What's wrong with it? It seems a configuration problem.

Comment: You're probably incorrectly using `<%=` when you meant to use `<%` for an `each` method call, but it's impossible to tell, because you didn't provide any actual code that causes the issue :( Also there's nothing like a hash here, there's a user instance in a collection.

Comment: I'm going to edit my post with your comments :-)

Comment: Did you change `= @tournament.users.each` to `- @tournaments.users.each`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: please give a clear problem statement, so that we don't have to guess.
Your problem seem to be that data is written to you html that you don't want. It looks like a ruby-array : `[#<User id: 29, country: "BE"....`

Is this what is wrong?

Replace the `=` with a `-` before `@tournament.users.each` .

reason: The `each` call iterates over the array, but also returns the whole array after finishing. If you use a '=', this return value will be written into your html.

Answer (score 0):

MurifoX was right!

> ```
> Did you change = @tournament.users.each to - @tournaments.users.each?
> ```

Of course, if you use '=' in HAML, it's translated like '<%='. But, if we use '-' instead of '=', it's translated like '<%'.

the reason (from Meier):

> reason: The each call iterates over the array, but also returns the whole array after finishing. If you use a '=', this return value will be written into your html.

That's it! Thank you everyone :-)

ps: When I can do it, I will up your answers :)

EDIT:
Dave Newton was right too ^^